# stringstream doesn't clean up completely?

Tags: c++, memory, stringstream

I'm working on what will be a pretty large and complicated system and trying to make sure it's as watertight as possible right from the start. Whilst running some memory checks, I noticed something odd when using stringstreams: they don't always seem to release all the memory when they get deleted/go out of scope.

I've tried searching the internet for answers, but most are old (so possibly out of date) and/or are more concerned with refreshing the contents than releasing the memory, so I've not really been able to tell if it's a known issue or a common mistake I'm making.

I've written a simple test to show what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

float getMemUsage(int& pid)
{
    if (pid < 0)
        pid = getpid();

    char buf[30];
    snprintf(buf, 30, "/proc/%u/statm", (unsigned)pid);
    FILE* pf = fopen(buf, "r");
    if (pf)
    {
        unsigned size; //       total program size
        //unsigned resident;//   resident set size
        //unsigned share;//      shared pages
        //unsigned text;//       text (code)
        //unsigned lib;//        library
        //unsigned data;//       data/stack
        //unsigned dt;//         dirty pages (unused in Linux 2.6)
        fscanf(pf, "%u" /* %u %u %u %u %u"*/, &size/*, &resident, &share, &text, &lib, &data*/);
        fclose(pf);

        return size/1024.0;
    }
    else
        return -1.0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        cerr << "no file specified\n";

    ifstream file;
    file.open(argv[1]);

    int pid = -1;    
    const float memUseAtStart = getMemUsage(pid);
    {
        float memUseBefore = getMemUsage(pid);
        stringstream sstream;
        float memUseAfter = getMemUsage(pid);
        cerr << "\tMemory use change after stringstream declaration: " << memUseAfter - memUseBefore << endl;

        memUseBefore = getMemUsage(pid);
        filebuf* pbuf = file.rdbuf();
        memUseAfter = getMemUsage(pid);
        cerr << "\tMemory use change after getting file buffer: " << memUseAfter - memUseBefore << endl;

        memUseBefore = getMemUsage(pid);
        sstream << pbuf;
        memUseAfter = getMemUsage(pid);
        cerr << "\tMemory use change after copying file contents: " << memUseAfter - memUseBefore << endl;

        memUseBefore = getMemUsage(pid);
        sstream.clear();
        sstream.str( string() );
        memUseAfter = getMemUsage(pid);
        cerr << "\tMemory use change after 'clearing': " << memUseAfter - memUseBefore << endl;
    }
    cerr << "Overall memory use change: " << getMemUsage(pid) - memUseAtStart << endl;

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives me the following output when called with a file larger than around 32K:

```
    Memory use change after stringstream declaration: 0
    Memory use change after getting file buffer: 0
    Memory use change after copying file contents: 0.0322266
    Memory use change after 'clearing': 0
Overall memory use change: 0.00195312
```

I'm running on Linux (SL6.6) and compiling with gcc 4.1.2 (though I've also tried clang and ICC with similar results).

Obviously, it's not a huge leak; it's just a little annoying that I can't make it completely tidy... Is there something I can/should do to release the memory manually? Or is it just something weird (with my setup and/or stringstream itself) I'll have to live with?

NB The intended use for the stringstream is to read in some file contents above and then parse them line by line; I would try using istringstream but I couldn't figure out how to set its value from the ifstream...

Thanks!

Comment: The process memory will not be shrinked by the OS, after freeing heap memory.

Comment: Repeat the block a few thousand times and see whether the memory usage keeps going up monotonically.

Comment: The C++ runtime doesn't always release memory back to the OS. That's not necessarily a leak.

Comment: I think there is a lot of grey area in your test case. E.g. Why do you use a compiler from 2007? What optimization flags do you use? Why do you mix language with OS specifics (`getMemUsage` and implementation of `sstream` are on different level of abstraction)? Why would you want system to free memory (it probably has a cost), when it's not needed? Maybe the system has it's own "garbage collecting".

Comment: Run it through Valgrind.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, the usage at the end seems to be fixed even after a few thousand runs; I guess it's just how it works then. I just wanted to check that it wasn't something I could/should "fix", as I've not seen it happen with other data types I've tested (plus there are quite a few search results for memory + stringstream); the tool I'm writing will be needing a lot of memory when it's done so I'm trying to keep a close eye on what's going on from the start.